# nginx location all but one

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

my nginx conf  has a location rule to remove trailing /

```
   location ~ ^(.+)/$ { 
       return  301  $1$is_args$args; 
   }
```

This works fine.

I have added an upstream server that distinguishes between trailing / in urls. So I want to proxy pass unaltered url

```
  location /biz {
      proxy_redirect     off;
      proxy_pass https://localhost:9443;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host   $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
   }
```

This works fine if I do not have the  first rule.  First rule removes the trailing slash and a post request that has trailing slash fails at upstream server because it expects that trailing slash

How can I have the first rule not applied to urls having  "biz" in them ?

Comment: Use the `^~` modifier: `location ^~ /biz/ { ... }`

Comment: That worked.  If you write that as answer, I will accept it